# Debugging NATS messages from Kubernetes event

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, nats.io

I have a simple script which watches Kubernetes events and then publishes a message to a NATS server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import asyncio
import argparse
import json
import logging
import os

from kubernetes import client, config, watch

from nats.aio.client import Client as NATS
from nats.aio.errors import ErrConnectionClosed, ErrTimeout, ErrNoServers

# monkey patch
from kube import local_load_oid_token
config.kube_config.KubeConfigLoader._load_oid_token = local_load_oid_token

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--in-cluster', help="use in cluster kubernetes config", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('-a', '--nats-address', help="address of nats cluster", default=os.environ.get('NATS_ADDRESS', None))
parser.add_argument('-d', '--debug', help="enable debug logging", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('-p', '--publish-events', help="publish events to NATS", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument('--output-events', help="output all events to stdout", action="store_true", dest='enable_output')
parser.add_argument('--connect-timeout', help="NATS connect timeout (s)", type=int, default=10, dest='conn_timeout')
parser.add_argument('--max-reconnect-attempts', help="number of times to attempt reconnect", type=int, default=1, dest='conn_attempts')
parser.add_argument('--reconnect-time-wait', help="how long to wait between reconnect attempts", type=int, default=10, dest='conn_wait')
args = parser.parse_args()

logger = logging.getLogger('script')
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
if args.debug:
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
else:
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

if not args.nats_address:
    logger.critical("No NATS cluster specified")
    exit(parser.print_usage())
else:
    logger.debug("Using nats address: %s", args.nats_address)

if args.in_cluster:
    config.load_incluster_config()
else:
    try:
        config.load_kube_config()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.critical("Error creating Kubernetes configuration: %s", e)
        exit(2)

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()


async def run(loop):
    nc = NATS()
    try:
        await nc.connect(args.nats_address, loop=loop, connect_timeout=args.conn_timeout, max_reconnect_attempts=args.conn_attempts, reconnect_time_wait=args.conn_wait)
        logger.info("Connected to NATS at %s..." % (nc.connected_url.netloc))
    except Exception as e:
        exit(e)

    #print("Connected to NATS at {}...".format(nc.connected_url.netloc))

    async def get_node_events():
        w = watch.Watch()
        for event in w.stream(v1.list_node):
            accepted = ["DELETED"]
            if event['type'] in accepted:
                logger.info("Event: %s %s %s" % (event['type'], event['object'].kind, event['object'].metadata.name))
                msg = {'type':event['type'],'object':event['raw_object']}
                logger.debug("Raw Message: %s"  % msg)
                await nc.publish("k8s_events", json.dumps(msg).encode('utf-8'))
                if args.enable_output:
                    print(json.dumps(msg))

    await get_node_events()
    await nc.flush(timeout=3)
    await nc.close()




if __name__ == '__main__':

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(run(loop))
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logger.info('keyboard shutdown')
        tasks = asyncio.gather(*asyncio.Task.all_tasks(loop=loop), loop=loop, return_exceptions=True)
        tasks.add_done_callback(lambda t: loop.stop())
        tasks.cancel()

        # Keep the event loop running until it is either destroyed or all
        # tasks have really terminated
        while not tasks.done() and not loop.is_closed():
            loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        logger.info('closing event loop')
        loop.close()
```

When running this with the event publishing enabled, I can see the event JSON being output.

However, for some reason my receiver isn't actually getting a NATS message for the deletion event.

- How can I debug the message made it onto the topic? Is there anything I can add which validates the message made it onto the topic via the code?
- Is my asyncio logic correct here?
- Why might the deletion event not make it onto the topic with this logic?

Comment: so `get_node_events` is not getting triggered?

Answer (score 2):

You can validate message delivery through the NATS server logs.  In configuring the NATS servers, temporarily enable debug/trace with the **-DV** flag passed to the NATS server or in the NATS configuration file with:

```
debug=true
trace=true
```

You should see something like this:

```
[31070] 2019/09/10 13:34:40.426198 [DBG] 127.0.0.1:53203 - cid:6 - Client connection created
[31070] 2019/09/10 13:34:40.426582 [TRC] 127.0.0.1:53203 - cid:6 - <<- [CONNECT {"verbose":false,"pedantic":false,"tls_required":false,"name":"NATS Sample Subscriber","lang":"go","version":"1.7.0","protocol":1,"echo":true}]
[31070] 2019/09/10 13:34:40.426614 [TRC] 127.0.0.1:53203 - cid:6 - <<- [PING]
[31070] 2019/09/10 13:34:40.426625 [TRC] 127.0.0.1:53203 - cid:6 - ->> [PONG]
[31070] 2019/09/10 13:34:40.426804 [TRC] 127.0.0.1:53203 - cid:6 - <<- [SUB k8s_events  1]
[31070] 2019/09/10 13:34:40.426821 [TRC] 127.0.0.1:53203 - cid:6 - <<- [PING]
[31070] 2019/09/10 13:34:40.426827 [TRC] 127.0.0.1:53203 - cid:6 - ->> [PONG]
[31070] 2019/09/10 13:34:44.167844 [DBG] ::1:53206 - cid:7 - Client connection created
[31070] 2019/09/10 13:34:44.168352 [TRC] ::1:53206 - cid:7 - <<- [CONNECT {"verbose":false,"pedantic":false,"tls_required":false,"name":"NATS Sample Publisher","lang":"go","version":"1.7.2","protocol":1,"echo":true}]
[31070] 2019/09/10 13:34:44.168383 [TRC] ::1:53206 - cid:7 - <<- [PING]
[31070] 2019/09/10 13:34:44.168390 [TRC] ::1:53206 - cid:7 - ->> [PONG]
[31070] 2019/09/10 13:34:44.168594 [TRC] ::1:53206 - cid:7 - <<- [PUB k8s_events 11]
[31070] 2019/09/10 13:34:44.168607 [TRC] ::1:53206 - cid:7 - <<- MSG_PAYLOAD: ["{json data}"]
[31070] 2019/09/10 13:34:44.168623 [TRC] 127.0.0.1:53203 - cid:6 - ->> [MSG k8s_events 1 11]
[31070] 2019/09/10 13:34:44.168648 [TRC] ::1:53206 - cid:7 - <<- [PING]
[31070] 2019/09/10 13:34:44.168653 [TRC] ::1:53206 - cid:7 - ->> [PONG]
```

Using the connection ID, you can see that connection ID 7 published 11 bytes to `k8s_events` (the protocol message `PUB k8s_events 11` with the message payload following it), and connection ID 6 (the subscriber) received the message (`MSG k8s_events 1 11`).

This is one way you can check that your client is publishing the message and your subscribers are listening to the correct subject.